# how to replace text in number list without changing its order in ms word using c# interop

Tags: c#, asp.net, interop, office-interop

I am replacing a text in number list in ms word. When it got replaced number list is not working. it shows as a paragraph. I want to replace the text without the change of the number list order. Please help. Thanks in advance!

```
newDocument = application.Documents.Open(strFilepath, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
        ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
foreach (Paragraph objParagraph in newDocument.Paragraphs)
{
   if (objParagraph.Range.Text.Contains("1st January 2015 to 31st December 2015"))
    {
        objParagraph.Range.Text = objParagraph.Range.Text.Replace("1st January 2015 to 31st December 2015", "1st January 2016 to 31st December 2016");
    }
}
```

Comment: if you don't mind include the code

Answer (score 0):

When you assign content to Paragraph.Range.Text you're replacing the entire paragraph, including the paragraph mark ("carriage return" = ANSI 13 = /r or /n in C#) at the end. The paragraph mark is not only a "carridge return", it also carries paragraph-level formatting information, which includes the numbering.

Try working with a Range object that is shortened by one character to exclude the paragraph mark:

```
Word.Range rngPara = objParagraph.Range;
//Note: You may need to pass the following params as objects, with ref
//instead of "in the clear", as below.
rngPara.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnit.wdCharacter, -1);
rngPara.Text = "abc";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you automate MS Word from an ASP.NET application.

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

Consider using any third-party components designed for the server-side execution, or just Open XML SDK. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.